Extracting the pages numbers from a word doc
I'm currently working on a VBA script that extracts the page number from all pages of the doc word, this one has a table at the footer of each page which contains a column specific for Pages (ex. 1/18), so the problem that I keep encountering is that it repeats the same number on all pages (ex. page X--->1/18 while it should be X/18)
Sub CheckNumber(fichierWord As String)
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim footer As Object
    Dim table As Object
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim pageNumber As String
    Dim totalPages As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim pageText As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Initialiser Word
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = False ' Garder Word invisible

    ' Ouvrir le fichier Word en lecture seule
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fichierWord, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Obtenir le nombre total de pages
    totalPages = wordDoc.ComputeStatistics(2) ' 2 correspond à wdStatisticPages

    ' Sélectionner la feuille Excel où écrire les résultats
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Boucle pour parcourir chaque page du document
    For i = 1 To totalPages
        ' Naviguer vers la page i
        wordApp.Selection.GoTo What:=3, Which:=1, Count:=i ' wdGoToPage = 3, wdGoToAbsolute = 1

        ' Accéder au pied de page principal de la page actuelle
        Set footer = wordDoc.Sections(wordApp.Selection.Information(3)).Footers(1) ' wdActiveEndSectionNumber = 3
        
        ' Vérifier s'il y a un tableau dans le pied de page
        If footer.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            ' Prendre le premier tableau du pied de page
            Set table = footer.Range.Tables(1)

            ' Vérifier si la table a au moins deux lignes et plusieurs colonnes
            If table.Rows.Count >= 2 And table.Columns.Count >= 4 Then
                ' Accéder à la dernière colonne de la deuxième ligne (cellule contenant le numéro de page)
                Set cell = table.cell(2, 4) ' Dernière colonne (4) à la deuxième ligne (2)
                pageText = Trim(cell.Range.Text)

                ' Nettoyer le texte extrait (enlever tous les caractères inutiles)
                pageText = Replace(pageText, Chr(13), "") ' Supprimer le retour chariot
                pageText = Replace(pageText, Chr(7), "")  ' Supprimer la fin de cellule
                pageText = Replace(pageText, "[", "") ' Supprimer les crochets, s'ils existent
                pageText = Replace(pageText, "]", "")
                pageText = Trim(pageText) ' Supprimer les espaces autour du texte

                ' Extraire seulement le numéro de page (avant le /)
                If InStr(pageText, "/") > 0 Then
                    pageNumber = Left(pageText, InStr(pageText, "/") - 1)
                End If

                ' Formater le numéro de page avec le total des pages
                pageNumber = pageNumber & "/" & totalPages

                ' Écrire le numéro de page dans la feuille Excel
                ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "Page " & i
                ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = "'" & pageNumber ' Préserver le format texte pour éviter la conversion en date
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            Else
                ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "Page " & i
                ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = "Tableau non conforme"
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "Page " & i
            ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = "Aucun tableau trouvé"
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' Fermer le document Word
    wordDoc.Close False
    wordApp.Quit
    Set wordApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Erreur lors de l'ouverture ou de la lecture du fichier Word: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    If Not wordApp Is Nothing Then
        wordApp.Quit
    End If
End Sub



The goal of this code is to automate the extraction of page numbers from the footer of a Word document and store them in an Excel sheet. Specifically, the code navigates through each page of the document, accesses the table in the footer, and retrieves the page number format (e.g., "1/18"). The target is to accurately collect and record these page numbers for all pages, ensuring that each page number is correctly identified and stored in sequence within the Excel sheet

wdGoToPage is 1, not 3

Set footer = wordDoc.Sections(wordApp.Selection.Information(3)).Footers(1) you're incrementing the page number, so this also increments the section number....  (3 = wdActiveEndPageNumber)  Double check all of your hard-coded Word constant values.

It seems pages are numbered sequentially, so you need to get the total number of pages only. Isn't it?

All you need for pageText is pageText = Split(Split(table.cell(2, 4).Range.Text, "[")(1), "]")(0)

the structure of the doc is normal ,it's not divided into sections (there's only header & footer format in the whole document ) at the footer there's a table which contains besides some columns a column which is reserved for page numbers (i think we may see this as a text ) the outcome is pages with same number (as he read the first value of page 1 and put it for the rest ) ,i assume also that there's not a delimeter which may allow me to referre to (like sections or sth) to treat pages independently even when i have used a counter to locate the current page doesn't work

Suggest you look at the comment by @Tim Williams again. Your .Goto What:= 3 is probably taking you to a Line, not a Page. For a small line number that is  probably going to take you to Page 1 every time.

i still encounter the same issue (copying the value  of the first page number for the rest) ,i don't know exactly which part (i have edited what to 1 ) i should act on to get this code working properly  (knowing that there's no sections format ,only header &footer format)

What I usually do when I cannot see what I am doing wrong is to step through my code using the features available in the VB Editor, particularly (a) the Locals Window, that lets me see the values of named variables, and (b) the Immediate Window, which lets me inspect more or less any variable value. In this case, I'd probably be looking at the range I was using to extract the page number, e.g. to make sure that the range.start and range.end were what I expected. But that's just my way.

Actually , i still struggle to find a way out to this issue ,i would know some can i rely on to scroll down pages and select the proper page each time because it keeps repeating the same page number of the first page for the rest , i'm treating this as a text (even if it's a dynamic incrementation )
